# Android: CountDownTimer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am trying to send a message (SMS as seen in the code) after a certain amount of time passed. But i don't think the CountDownTimer is working properly because it sends the first message as soon as the notification is shown.

Here is the code below

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2Activity.class);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);

    mManager.notify(0, notification);

    CountDownTimer waitTimer;
    waitTimer = new CountDownTimer(180000, 60000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            sendmessage();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //After 60000 milliseconds (60 sec) finish current
            //if you would like to execute something when time finishes
        }
    }.start();


}
```

So how can I make the timer wait properly ? Because as I said it sends the first message as soon as the notification is called.

Note: And if the user taps on the notification it opens an activity which is supposed to kill the CountDownTimer but I couldn't achive that. How can do that ? I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observing the `CountDownTimer` reveals that first time `onTick()` is called immediately after calling `onStart()` and after that it is called after specified intervals as specified.

Secondly the first parameter passed `180000` tells the timer to call onFinish() after `180000` mills and call onTick() after `60000` millis in between starting immediately. If you want to restrict it to not send message the first time than you can do this simple check like this:

```
CountDownTimer waitTimer;
waitTimer = new CountDownTimer(180000, 60000) {
        boolean firstTime = true;
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (firstTime) {
                firstTime = false;
                return;
            }

            sendmessage();
        }
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        //After 180000 milliseconds finish current
        //if you would like to execute something when time finishes
    }
}.start();
```

OR

You can also use TimerTask to perform the same operation:

```
Timer waitingTimer = new Timer();
waitingTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendMessage();
        // Add a base condition here to cancel the task if needed..
    }
}, 60000, 180000);
```

Comment: So what should i use instead of CountDownTimer to make it wait for specified amount of time ?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement with the below code,give intervalTime as your waiting time in millisecs.

```
Timer waitingTimer = new Timer();
waitingTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendMessage();
        waitingTimer.cancel();
    }
}, intervalTime, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer and TimerTask for this. You can set a delay to run and for repeating you can set a time after which it should execute again.

Example:

```
Timer timer = null;

public void scheduleTimer (){
    cancelTimer(); // Cancel scheduled timer if any.
    timer = new Timer("message_sender");
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        //This timer will execute timertask with first delay of 2 seconds and repeat it every 3 seconds.
      }
    }, 2000, 3000);
}

//Method for cancelling any scheduled timer
private void cancelTimer(){
    if (timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
    }
}
```

If you want to do any UI level task then inside run() you would require to execute code by using `runOnUiThread`